# What does this do? var1$resid [ ]

Tags: r, sample

I haven't used R since 2009 (I was using it very casually even back then). I am  not programming in R now either. However, I need to understand what the second line does here (sorry if my question is rather naive!):

```
var1 <- VAR.est(x, p, type)

es <- var1$resid[sample(n-p, n, replace=TRUE),,drop=FALSE]
```

Does it sample from the residual distribution of the var.est regression with replacement? 
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: i did not understand question

Comment: what does this do : es <- var1$resid[sample(n-p, n, replace=TRUE),,drop=FALSE]

Comment: can you post piece of code so I can run in System

Comment: var1 <- VAR.est(x, p, type)
    b <- var1$coef  # OLS estimates
    mat <- matrix(0, nrow = k, ncol = ncol(b))
    for (i in 1:nb) {
        ## es <- VAR.etp:::resamp(e)
        es <- var1$resid[sample(n-p, n, replace=TRUE),,drop=FALSE]
        ## xs <- VAR.etp:::VAR.ys(x, b, p, es, type)
        xs <- VAR.ys2(x, b, p, es, type)
        bs <- VAR.est2(xs, p, type, coef.only=TRUE)$coef
        mat <- mat + bs/nb
    }

Comment: so its part of a bootstrap. so the line I want to figure out is just some residual bootstrap probably. But I like to know exactly what it does

Comment: I am unable to run your code

Comment: @Tina Please put additional information (e.g. the code) in your question (not in a comment), i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49407195/edit

Comment: @Tina , edit your post and paste your code before paste press **Ctrl+K**, otherwise mail me, sandipnd31@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The end result seems to be `n-p` random rows (with replacement) from the residuals matrix `resid`, which is itself an attribute of the object `var1`.

`drop = TRUE` shrinks the matrix to the lowest possible dimension. From `help("[")`:

> ...
>
> drop: For matrices and arrays.  If 'TRUE' the result is coerced to
>             the lowest possible dimension (see the examples).  This only
>             works for extracting elements, not for the replacement.  See           'drop' for further details.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!